# Microsoft Graph Get Presence Application Permission Type

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Currently the following endpoint does not have support for application permissions. I would like to use this in my application for message routing to designated backup users if a user is unavailable.

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/66825e03-7ef5-42da-9069-724602c31f6b/presence

Currently Permission type for Application is Not Supported.

Is it in the plans to make this a supported feature?

We would really appreciate it!

Comment: You can try voting here: https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39219637-application-permission-for-presence

It's a mess to try to do anything server-side with it right now.  Best I've come up with is having a user sign into a portal, capturing their access token, and using that for the presence api...  Which is disgusting and horrible, but it kind of works.